# React Typescript Custom Hook Sort List

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a custom hook in react to return a sorted array based on two arguments: the list itself and a string with the key I want to sort.
Just tried several strategies before asking how to solve that, lot's of hours cursing TS, but still have the faith it has a simple solution I'm not seeing.

the Hook:

```
type Item = {
  [key: string]: number | string,
}

function useSortList(list: Item[], key: string) {

  return list.sort((a: object, b: object) => a[key] > b[key] ? 1 : -1) || list;

}

export default useSortList;
```

On `a[key] > b[key]` I'm getting this error:

> Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{}'.
> No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type '{}'.ts(7053)

I.e.: I'm passing as list a simple movies array of objects and trying to sort this by 'title'.

How could I type this sort parameters so I can use this with any array of objects?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are using `object` type. Try removing this type annotation.

Since the type of `list` variable is well defined, `list.sort` is well defined as well, no need to try and help TypeScript with this ([see](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAksEFsoF4oG8BQUoG0DWEIAXFAM7ABOAlgHYDmAuiTQK4IBGEFUAPmZbToAaDAF8MGAGYsaAY2BUA9jSgtSEAMqKKwADJVyACgA2B4CTiIcDIVALF+1egEp0E7BQjAWFFafIAdKTawIaGAIa27K7IAHxQ4fiEDFDx7EkgKQD8UACMUCQAtLmuPHz+wADcEuIYEAAeYCFQACYQkuEsxsCq6lo6+uTVQA)).